# Asymptotic behaviour of exponential functions and their inverses

Tags: limits, asymptotics

If $a > b > 0$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {a^x}{b^x} = \infty $

So we $a^x$ grows faster than $b^x$

Doing the same thing for their inverses yields: $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\log_ax}{\log_bx} = \frac {\log b}{\log a} \neq 0$

Intuitively since $a^x$ grows faster than $b^x$, one would assume that the inverse of $a^x$ would grow slower that the inverse of $b^x$. After all their graphs are just the mirror images across $y = x$. It appears that algebraicaly we do not reach that conclusion? Is there an intuitive explanation of this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but in this case, your two functions have derivatives which tend to infinity when $x\to\infty$. This gives that the derivatives of the inverses tend to $0$ as $x\to\infty$. So, the graphs of the inverses become flatter as $x\to\infty$. With this picture in mind, the fact that the quotient stabilizes is not so surprising.

Comment: What is your definition of inverse?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions